# How can I create méthod edit data using reactjs ,formik and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, formik

Hello  how can I create a edit or update function in the same component using reactjs hooks ,formik and axios  , I create function add but I have problem to create edit function I’m new in react
I knew for creating edit function I would be use axios.put , I use it but I can’t render data in the form edit inputs,
The edit form inputs are always empty
This is my code

```
export default function CreateOrgan(props)  {
    /* Server State Handling */
    const [serverState, setServerState] = useState();
    const handleServerResponse = (ok, msg) => {
        setServerState({ok, msg});
    };
    const handleOnSubmit = (values, actions) => {
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/organs",
            data: values
        })
            .then(response => {
                props.history.push("/listorgan");
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
                actions.resetForm();
                alert("Organ enregister avec succer");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
                handleServerResponse(false, error.response.data.error);
            });
    };
    return (
        
                                    <PageWrapper>
                        <Formik
                            initialValues={{ id: "", nom: ""}}
                            onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}
                            validationSchema={formSchema}
                        >
                            {({ isSubmitting,
                                  values,
                                  errors,
                                  touched,
                                  isValidating,
                                  isValid
                            }) => (
                                <Form id="fs-frm" noValidate>
                                <Row>
                                <Col>
                                    <Label htmlFor="code">
                                        Code
                                        <Input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="id"
                                            autoCorrect="off"
                                            autoComplete="name"
                                            placeholder="Code"
                                            valid={touched.id && !errors.id}
                                            error={touched.id && errors.id}
                                        />
                                    </Label>
                                    {errors.id && touched.id && (
                                        <StyledInlineErrorMessage>
                                            {errors.id}
                                        </StyledInlineErrorMessage>
                                    )}
                                </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <Label htmlFor="code">
                                            Nom
                                            <Input
                                                type="text"
                                                name="nom"
                                                autoCorrect="off"
                                                autoComplete="name"
                                                placeholder="Nom"
                                                valid={touched.nom && !errors.nom}
                                                error={touched.nom && errors.nom}
                                            />
                                        </Label>
                                        {errors.nom && touched.nom && (
                                            <StyledInlineErrorMessage>
                                                {errors.nom}
                                            </StyledInlineErrorMessage>
                                        )}
                                </Col>
                                </Row>
                                    <Card.Footer style={{ "textAlign": "right" }}>
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={isSubmitting} style={{ "width": "120px", "margin": "1px", "padding": "2px" }}>
                                        Submit
                                    </button>
                                    </Card.Footer>
                                    {serverState && (
                                        <p className={!serverState.ok ? "errorMsg" : ""}>
                                            {serverState.msg}
                                        </p>
                                    )}
                                </Form>
                            )}
                        </Formik>
                                        </PageWrapper>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: the **PUT method** replaces the original version of your request while the **PATCH method** modifies the specified portion contained in your request.

Secondly: If your intention is to modify with a PATCH method, then you need to modify your **handleOnSubmit** like so -

````
axios({method: "PATCH",url: "/organs", data: values})
.then(response => { props.history.push("/listorgan");
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    actions.resetForm();
    alert("Organ enregister avec succer"); })
.catch(error => {
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    handleServerResponse(false, error.response.data.error); 
})```
````